# TYPO3 encrypted mailto-link (javascript:linkTo_UnCryptMailto) not working with subject and body

Tags: encryption, typo3

In TYPO3 mailto links are decrypted by the following code snippet.
Is there a way to use this with mailto links, which contain subject and body text?

e.g.: email@example.org?subject=This is my subject&body=This is my bodytext: more text...etc.

```
    // decrypt helper function
function decryptCharcode(n,start,end,offset) {
    n = n + offset;
    if (offset > 0 && n > end) {
        n = start + (n - end - 1);
    } else if (offset < 0 && n < start) {
        n = end - (start - n - 1);
    }
    return String.fromCharCode(n);
}
    // decrypt string
function decryptString(enc,offset) {
    var dec = "";
    var len = enc.length;
    for(var i=0; i < len; i++) {
        var n = enc.charCodeAt(i);
        if (n >= 0x2B && n <= 0x3A) {
            dec += decryptCharcode(n,0x2B,0x3A,offset); // 0-9 . , - + / :
        } else if (n >= 0x40 && n <= 0x5A) {
            dec += decryptCharcode(n,0x40,0x5A,offset); // A-Z @
        } else if (n >= 0x61 && n <= 0x7A) {
            dec += decryptCharcode(n,0x61,0x7A,offset); // a-z
        } else {
            dec += enc.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return dec;
}
    // decrypt spam-protected emails
function linkTo_UnCryptMailto(s) {
    location.href = decryptString(s,-3);
}
```

Comment: if you have problems with the link generation inspect the link generation without spamprotection. as TYPO3 has a very special data format for (any kind of) links you can easily run into problems with it (independent of spamprotection).

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, that works for me (TYPO3 v10).

TypoScript setup:

```
config.spamProtectEmailAddresses = -3
```

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Setup/Config/Index.html#spamprotectemailaddresses

Fluid:

```
<f:link.email email="my@email.tld?subject=123&body=Hello there!">link</f:link.email>
```

That opens my E-Mail-Client with subject and body (Firefox 84, Thunderbird).

Comment: It works with a Single word but NOT with the example above: ....subject=Hello i contain spaces - and other: stuff&body=i contain spaces und linebreaks

Comment: You have to urlencode your string: `<f:link.email email="my@example.com.tld?subject=123&body={f:format.urlencode(value:'Hello i contain spaces - and other: stuff')}">link</f:link.email>`

Comment: I did this.. but this does either not work correct with the encrypt js...

Comment: in TYPO3v10 this works for me even with spaces. %20 also produces spaces but it is not needed. - I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

if it does not run by default (maybe it depends on usage, from where to what app, but I remember that I used it already).
You might need to encode special characters for usage in URLs.
Try to use PHP function `urlencode`.
So you could replace all spaces with `%20` or `+`.

Comment: if your mail app does not handle it correctly you can't do anything on side of TYPO3. maybe your browser or your operating system is involved. please identify the problem ('it does not work' is no description so anyone can identify the error and give a solution)

Comment: HAs nothing to do with mail client. I think  %20 or + are not encrypted correct by the js. i wonder if anyone has the same problem and maybe a solution ;)

Comment: if I build a mail link from fluid (`f:link.typolink parameter="mailto:noone@example.com?subject=mail%20from%20fluid&body=test%20test">mail</f:link.typolink>`) which contains `%20`or `+` the whole is transferred to the target program as is (TYPO3 8.7). If I have spaces in the link the arguments are splitted (as expected) into link-target and link-title ... (therefore it is important how the link is stored  and rendered). If I use `f:link.email` I can use spaces in the `email`parameter without the need to substitute them.